# How to check if a property is defined in Jenkinsfile or not

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins function like this:

```
def function() {
    wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
        script {
            ....
            def triggeredBy = "Jenkins"
            if(BUILD_USER_EMAIL) {
              triggeredBy = "<mention email='${BUILD_USER_EMAIL}'/>"
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The property BUILD_USER_EMAIL is fron the BuildUser class. If a user triggered the build, it will contain the email of the user. If Jenkins triggered it automatically, this property is not defined.

I tried to do it in the above code but it does not work. I still get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BUILD_USER_EMAIL for class: WorkflowScript
```

I think it crashed because of the if statement is trying to use BUILD_USER_EMAIL which does not exist.

What I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to solve this issue:

```
def function() {
    wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
        script {
            ....
            def triggeredBy = "Jenkins"

            try{ 
                 triggeredBy = "<mention email='${BUILD_USER_EMAIL}'/>"
            } catch (error){
                 println "BUILD_USER_EMAIL not supplied using default value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will work but I don't quite want to treat the absence of BUILD_USER_EMAIL as an exception.

Comment: This is how Jenkins treat it, I didn't liked it either when I searched for it but this is the only way I found if you find another way please share.